# How to set flat/double values to layout parameters programmatically...?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have Relative layout to which i want to set width 1.4dp

How to do that.. If any have any idea please help.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can only give integer values to layout parameters

source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

No matter what the layout is you can never give a float value.

“dip” or “dp” or “dps” - Density-independent Pixels my friend which means you can't divide a fraction into another fraction.

```
pixels = dps * (density / 160).
```

For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dp would equal 1.5 physical pixels.

Comment: This comment is wrong. The LayoutParams methods involving size are in PIXEL units, which is why they are ints. Layout values can and are specified in float units (e.g. 1.6dp).

Answer (score 3):

According to this reference you can use decimal places for views:

android:layout_height and android:layout_width - May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_height